# Access Key in Associative array which is stored in variable

Tags: javascript, arrays, associative-array

I am currently dealing with this problem. I have an associative array **imageDict={}**. The key to this imageDict is another Object called **image** and value is yet another associative array, with **string** as Key and **array** as value. So **imageDict[image] = {}**, and **imageDict[image]["string"] = []**.

The problem I have is that the key **image** is an object with some key/values stored in it aswell for example, **width,height,top,left** and so on. And at some point **I store imageDict[image] into var animationQueue** and send it as parameter to **function animation(animationQueue)**, where I access its values as animationQueue["string"].... But what I would like to do is also access the **Key image** which is hidden in **animationQueue since animationQueue = imageDict[image]** and change some of its values. Is it possible to do this?

Comment: What is the point of trying to use an object as a key.. Why don't you just insert the value into the object as a separate property. If you must.. then use Maps which would take anything as key or value.

Comment: It was just the way I set up my code and build on it, until I came to this problem. And before I change my code I wanted to know if there was easier way to do this. But it seems theres not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need access to the image object, why not just pass it as a second parameter to your function `function animation(animationQueue, image)`, or are you not able to change the animation function? I do not believe there is a way to pass the value of an associate array to a function, as you are, and from the value to get the key from the value. The value does not inherently store a reference to the key.

Comment: There surely is way to change function, but I wanted to be sure before I changed anything major.